# what is the easiest way to edit solrconfig.xml?

Tags: xml, solr, solrj

I am trying to override solrconfig.xml but I am having trouble understanding config API and curl. What is the easiest way to edit solrconfig.xml, directly or through an API?

Comment: What is your system? Linux..Windows? 
for me it is better to do it directly via the server with vi under linux for example.
Do not forget to restart solr after each change

Comment: windows. what's vi?

Comment: vi is a text editor under linux 
But you are under windows using a classic file editor.
do not hesitate to read documentation about the configuration of this file

Comment: you can use the examples /solr/example/example-DIH/ to test and understand how these files work

Comment: Is it not possible to edit it directly with notepad c++ ?

Comment: Yes it is possible and I recommend it to you. With each modification, it is necessary to restart solr to take into account the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a simple text editor (e.g. vi on Linux/Mac, Notepad or Notepad++ on Windows).

Don't forget to restart Solr after the config change and to monitor the Solr log files to check for errors.